# Pandas, сортировка колонок

Tags: pandas, сортировка

Есть датафрейм, к примеру:

```
         колонка 1    колонка 2   колонка 3
строка 1    5            7            9
```

А нужно чтобы колонки располагались в порядке убывания по строке:

```
         колонка 1    колонка 2   колонка 3
строка 1    9            7            5
```

Не нашел нигде указаний как сортировать именно столбы, а не строки.

Comment: Можно попробовать через `df.sort_values(by=df.index[0], axis=1, ascending=False)`, это отсортирует по убыванию, но индексы колонок при выводе будут соответственно заменены, в этом примере на: колонка 3, колонка 2, колонка 1.

Comment: @M141
В целом схема работает, благодарю =)